# Datetime expression in JPA by passing as parameter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datetime

I want to compare a datetime function in the JPA. Just wondering how to pass it. By the way I am very new to JPA. My input date will look like this `28/12/2014 16:20` and I am parsing it as date

I have to pass this as a parameter but the database table (MS SQL) consists of datetime format as `2014-12-28 16:20:38.107`

Here is my code.

Under `@Entity` (I cannot edit this code since I don't have permissions to do so. Anyway other methods are accessing this entities, I am just reusing it)

```
    @Column(name = "PublishDate", nullable = false)
    private Date publishDate;
```

My Actual Code

```
    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(s);
    Message.findByPublishDate(date);
```

After running the above code with `Debug=true` I have seen the passed parameter in the sql query as:
`messages0_.PublishDate=?` that means it's not even taking the date and I get the below exception

```
select operations0_.OperationsMessageID as Operatio1_10_, operations0_.Content as Content2_10_, 
operations0_.CreatedDate as CreatedD3_10_, operations0_.ExpiryDate as ExpiryDa4_10_, 
operations0_.PublishDate as PublishD5_10_, operations0_.Status as Status6_10_, operations0_.Title 
as Title7_10_, operations0_.OperationsMessageTypeID as Operatio8_10_ from OperationsMessage 
operations0_ where operations0_.PublishDate=?
```

Exception Details:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:172)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:155)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:105)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.findByPublishDate(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please show the query

Comment: Steve, Added Query thanks

Comment: That is the generated SQL, we need to see the JPQL query. Also, what is the SQL column type of `PublishDate`.

Comment: public OperationsMessage findByPublishDate(Date publishDate); - thats the one, I am using crud

Comment: That's not the query, it's just a method call. Show the source code for this method

Comment: Actually I am using JPA not JPQL http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good chance that your Spring Data generated JPQL query is not working because your column definition is missing the [@Temporal](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Temporal.html) annotation. The spec says that this annotation **must** be specified to any `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar` type of column.

I realise that you have said that you cannot change it, but I don't think there is an option:

```
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "PublishDate", nullable = false)
    private Date publishDate;
```

You might need TemporalType.TIMESTAMP if the physical database column is a timestamp SQL type.

Alternatively, the column has been specified as a [java.sql.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html). If this is the case then perhaps you need to use that date type as your argument to `findByPublishDate`, converting from your java.util.Date:

```
    Message.findByPublishDate(new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need parse your date parameter , see this example:

```
query.setParameter("publishDate", publishDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
```

You just set the parameter with the type of parameter you want, in this case a timestamp, so you can use TemporalType.TIMESTAMP .

Comment: yes,you just need to change your  your query object and set in your jpql statement the parameter. Show the code inside your findByPublishDate method.